# Why does vmware-cmd need a target host when working with vCenter server?

Tags: vmware

On Windows systems, using VMware PowerCLI, I can connect to a vCenter server using appropriate credentials:

```
Connect-VIServer myvcenter.example.com
```

Once connected, I can run `Get-VM` to see a list of registered VMs. Note that I need not know names of ESX hosts connected to this vCenter server.

When using `vmware-cmd`, for the similar `-l` option, both these options need to be provided:

```
-H <host>
Specifies an ESX/ESXi host or a vCenter Server system.

-h | --vihost <esx_host>
Specifies a target host if the host specified by -H <host> is a vCenter Server system.
```

Why is that so?

How to list VMs if one does not know the ESX hosts on this vCenter (without using VMware PowerCLI)? I am trying to get this working over SSH on a GNU+Linux system.

Versions:

```
vSphere SDK for Perl version: 6.5.0
Script 'vmware-cmd' version: 6.5.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply discarded VMware CLI and started using https://github.com/snobear/ezmomi. After having a `config.yml` file with only connection related options, I was able to list VMs (without knowing ESX hosts).

Comment: GOVC too works https://github.com/vmware/govmomi/tree/master/govc without needing to know the ESX host

Answer (score 0):

vmware-cmd is the legacy way that was provided back in the 3.x days to do CLI tasks directly from the ESX service console.

Since you're using vSphere 6.5, I would look at the new CLI called Datacenter CLI (DCLI) instead: http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-6-5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.dcli.cmdref.doc%2Fintro.html

Comment: I need to work with vSphere 5.5. Now trying DCLI ... will share my findings.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work. I'm SSH'd into a totally different linux VM that has nothing (VMware related) but VMware-vSphere-CLI-6.5.0-4566394.x86_64.tar.gz installed. Command dcli keeps showing Error: Unable to connect to the server.